# Swift gives file doesn't exist error but file indeed exist

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working in an iOS app (with SwiftUI) that analyzes files. The user selects a file with Files app, the app copies that file into their internal storage, in a temporary file, analyzes it and then remove the temporary file.
This is working almost everytime, but a few users have reported problems.
The logs shows that for these users the copy fails because the selected file does not exist, but it indeed exists, it has been selected just a second ago.

This is my code:

```
struct AnalyzeFileView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var observedModel: AnalyzeFileViewAdapter
    @State var hasToOpenFilesApp = false

    CustomButton(title: "Open file picker") {
            hasToOpenFilesApp = true
    }.fileImporter(isPresented: $hasToOpenFilesApp, allowedContentTypes: [.text, .zip]) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let url):
            manageSelectedFile(url: url)
        case .failure(let error):
            manageError(error)
        }
    }
    .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(style: .terciary, size: .large, isFullWidth: true))
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)
    .padding(.bottom, 24)

    private func manageSelectedFile(url: URL) {
        
        print("1.AnalyzeFileView::manageSelectedFile.url=[\(url)]")
        observedModel.selectedFile = url
        guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
        print("2.AnalyzeFileView::manageSelectedFile.url=[\(url)]")
        observedModel.presenter?.manageFilePicked(url: url)
        url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    }
}

class AnalyzeFilePresenter: NSObject {
    
    func manageFilePicked(url: URL) {
    
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let directoryPaths = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let publicDocumentsDir = directoryPaths.first
        print("3.manageFilePicked.pathToFilePicked=[\(url.absoluteString)]")
        if let destinationURL = publicDocumentsDir?.appendingPathComponent("temporaryfile.\(url.pathExtension)") {
            
            print("4.manageFilePicked.destinationURL=[\(destinationURL)]")
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
                do {
                    print("4.1.manageFilePicked.trying to remove item at=[\(destinationURL.path)]")
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: destinationURL.path)
                } catch {
                    print("4.2.manageFilePicked.error trying to remove item=[\(error)]")
                }
            }
            do {
                
                print("5.manageFilePicked.trying to copy item from [\(url)] to [\(destinationURL)]")
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: url, to: destinationURL)
                self.pathFromFileBrowser = destinationURL.path
                print("5.1.manageFilePicked.pathFromFileBrowser=[\(pathFromFileBrowser ?? "nil")]")
    
                // Continue with the file analysis
            } catch {
                print("5.2.manageFilePicked.error trying to copy item=[\(error)]")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the log for this code when it fails to copy:

```
1.AnalyzeFileView::manageSelectedFile.url=[file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCB7473D-918D-47E3-81E1-32AC42308635/File%20Provider%20Storage/17841195/1-sWkb-UyRP6HpLZE7-ghKaMeJK_r8i9g/MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip]

2.AnalyzeFileView::manageSelectedFile.url=[file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCB7473D-918D-47E3-81E1-32AC42308635/File%20Provider%20Storage/17841195/1-sWkb-UyRP6HpLZE7-ghKaMeJK_r8i9g/MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip]

3.manageFilePicked.pathToFilePicked=[file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCB7473D-918D-47E3-81E1-32AC42308635/File%20Provider%20Storage/17841195/1-sWkb-UyRP6HpLZE7-ghKaMeJK_r8i9g/MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip]

4.manageFilePicked.destinationURL=[file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CCA3B674-5FF4-458D-9312-B0CA9C25E831/Documents/temporaryfile.zip]

5.manageFilePicked.trying to copy item from [file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCB7473D-918D-47E3-81E1-32AC42308635/File%20Provider%20Storage/17841195/1-sWkb-UyRP6HpLZE7-ghKaMeJK_r8i9g/MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip] to [file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CCA3B674-5FF4-458D-9312-B0CA9C25E831/Documents/temporaryfile.zip]

5.2.manageFilePicked.error trying to copy item=[Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/FCB7473D-918D-47E3-81E1-32AC42308635/File Provider Storage/17841195/1-sWkb-UyRP6HpLZE7-ghKaMeJK_r8i9g/MyFileToBeAnalysed.zip, NSUnderlyingError=0x2810dd710 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}]
```

Why is there a "no such file" error if file does exist? I'm using startAccessingSecurityScopedResource and stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource to access and copy the file, so I'm not sure if this is a permissions problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context but whenever I hit "works almost every time except a few cases", I'd lean towards a race condition.

Comment: good point barndog, I'll check this possibility. I was thinking more of a permissions issue, source files in places where fileimporter cannot read directly, things like that.

Comment: That's also possible! I'm not incredibly familiar with the Files apis but there may be a permissions check that needs to happen that's not